# zPosition and subviews array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I have the following problem: I want to have constants, defining the order of a subviews in `parentView.subviews` array. This constants doesn't have to be indexes of subview's array, but they can.

Something like this:

```
#define VIEW1_INDEX 10 // or 0, if it's an index 
#define VIEW2_INDEX 20 // or 1, if it's an index
```

And that would mean, that `parentView.subviews` array is `{view1, view2}`.

---

First I tried to use CALayer's zPosition property.

Say I have two subviews of `parentView`: `view1` and `view2`and they have the same size and frames. `parentView.subviews` array is `{view1, view2}` (in this order).
If I do

```
view2.layer.zPosition = VIEW2_INDEX;
view1.layer.zPosition = VIEW1_INDEX;
```

than the display order of subviews changes, but tap handling order and `parentView.subviews` array remains unchanged, so I see `view1` at the top, tap on it, but this tap is handled by `view2`, which is not what I expect.

So I need to change display order and event handling order simultaneously.

My best idea is to use code, that sets new zPosition alway together with code, that changes subviews array:

```
view2.layer.zPosition = 0;
NSUInteger* index = [parentView.subviews indexOfObject:view2];
[parentView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:index];
```

But this doesn't seems to be the best solution.

---

Other idea was to use `[parentView insertSubview:atIndex:]` instead of `[parentView addSubview]`, but than I would need to make sure that I'm inserting views in proper order, which is a little tiresome, as I have about 15 views being created in different places.

---

So here is finally the question: is there a way to solve the problem, described in the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about assigning the subviews' tags 1..15 (if there are 15) according to the desired stacking order.  Place them all in an array which you then sort by tag.  Iterate the array, adding them to the superview.

I'm not sure how they are created, but let's say they are contained in some array in in arbitrary order:

```
NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray array];

UIView *subview9 = [[UIView alloc] init];
subview9.tag = 9;
[views addObject:subview9];

// and so on, in arbitrary order for subview1, subview2, subview3
// remember tag == 0 is no good, because it will be undistinguishable in viewWithTag
// from unassigned tags
```

Sort an array:

```
[views sortUsingComparator:^(UIView *vA, UIView *vB) {
    return vA.tag - vB.tag;
}];
```

Add them to the superview, now sorted:

```
for (UIView *view in views) {
    [theViewThatContainsThemInTagOrder addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use zPosition it will just move the layer (the visual part), but everything will be working like nothing has changed.  Try by using this:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:view1];
```

or

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view2];
```